# Sony ZV-1M2 Programmatic Remote Control Availability (WiFi or USB)

Tags: macos, camera, sony-camera-api

I want to control multiple cameras for full body scanning, and I'm starting with the one ZV-1M2 I have. Through Sony's documentation, neither new SDK(2021~) nor SDK Beta(2017) support this type. Just wonder can I use some traditional ways, like WiFi, to call the API?

Also, regarding multiple camera controls, what approach may be most feasible?

Thanks for any advice!

I have tested that WiFi connection is working, but the device description doesn't look like what I should get according to SDK Beta document:

```
<serviceList>
            <service>
                <serviceType>urn:schemas-sony-com:service:DigitalImaging:1</serviceType>
                <serviceId>urn:schemas-sony-com:serviceId:DigitalImaging</serviceId>
                <SCPDURL>/DigitalImagingDesc.xml</SCPDURL>
                <controlURL>/upnp/control/DigitalImaging</controlURL>
                <eventSubURL></eventSubURL>
            </service>
        </serviceList>
        <av:X_ScalarWebAPI_DeviceInfo xmlns:av="urn:schemas-sony-com:av">
            <av:X_ScalarWebAPI_ImagingDevice>
                <av:X_ScalarWebAPI_LiveView_URL>
                    http://192.168.122.1:60152/liveviewstream?%211234%21%2a%3a%2a%3aimage%2fjpeg%3a%2a%21%21%21%21%21</av:X_ScalarWebAPI_LiveView_URL>
                <av:X_ScalarWebAPI_DefaultFunction>RemoteShooting</av:X_ScalarWebAPI_DefaultFunction>
            </av:X_ScalarWebAPI_ImagingDevice>
        </av:X_ScalarWebAPI_DeviceInfo>
```

The `ActionList_URL` and `ServiceType` are missing, so I can't locate the endpoint to call API

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.